# How to implement a getComponent(/*Class*/) method for video game in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I'm writing in kotlin, developing a text based RPG game for android.
I'm currently at the development of my object system going with a strategy / entity component design.
I'm stuck on the getComponent function and have no clue what I'm doing

I need a method that accepts a reference to a Class type and then compares that to all the component instance's class types.

I've tried using generics, KClass, Java Type but can't find the answer.

My main issue is the "as" operator. I have no clue what it accepts.

All I got so far is :

```
fun getComponent(clazz : KClass<*>) : Component? {
    for(component in components) {
        if(component is clazz) {
            return component
        }
    }
    return null
}
```

This code is wrong. IntelliJ alerts me that clazz does not exist as it's not ann actual Class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a `KClass` instance, which is a runtime object representing a type, used for reflection. You have two main options here. You can use [reified generics](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters), like so, which allows you to avoid using reflection entirely:

```
inline fun <reified T : Component> getComponent() : T? {
    for(component in components) {
        if(component is T) {
            return component
        }
    }
    return null
}
```

This method can be invoked like so:

```
getComponent<SomeClass>()
```

Alternatively, you can use [KClass.isInstance](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-class/is-instance.html):

```
fun getComponent(clazz : KClass<*>) : Component? {
    for(component in components) {
        if(clazz.isInstance(component)) {
            return component
        }
    }
    return null
}
```

You can make this a little bit more convenient with generics and casting as well:

```
fun <T : Component> getComponent(clazz : KClass<*>) : T? {
    for(component in components) {
        if(clazz.isInstance(component)) {
            return component as T
        }
    }
    return null
}
```

For both of these, the usage is the same:

```
getComponent(SomeClass::class)
```

Comment: Thank you. This saved me alot of time. I'll look more into inline functions as then I don't need the entirety of the reflections library.

Comment: For possible future reference: reified inline functions compile slower (if used in many places - they act like c++ templates) and cannot be called from other, non-reified generic functions. Reified functions are a necessary evil because of the JVM's type erasure. Passing around KClass (or Class) is a better, more compatible way on the JVM. You can then have reified inline one-line function "wrapper" around that to make the calling site nicer.